# How to convert a string into a snake case?

Tags: string, go

I have a list of strings:

```
  myStrings = []string{
    "MyString1",
    "SomeName33",
    "AaaBbbTutu",
    "JaaaKooooTooo"
  }
```

How do I convert them into case snake strings?

```
  mySnakeCaseStrings = []string{
    "my_string1",
    "some_name33",
    "aaa_bbb_tutu",
    "jaaa_koooo_tooo"
  }
```

For there's no special function in `strings` for this. And doing it manually, by custom code, would be a lot of work for such a simple task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is what a dedicated library like [`iancoleman/strcase`](https://github.com/iancoleman/strcase) is for:

It has a function `ToSnake(s)` which will produce `any_kind_of_string` from `s := "AnyKind of_string"`.